# When checking if user exists some of my code is not executed?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa, thymeleaf

I'm working on a small Spring MVC project.

```
package...
imports...

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/auth")
public class AuthenticationController {

    private final UserService userService;

    public AuthenticationController(UserService userService) {
        this.userService = userService;
    }

    @GetMapping("/login")
    public String showLoginPage() {
        System.out.println("Login form");
        return "authentication/login-page";
    }

    @GetMapping("/register")
    public String showRegisterPage(Model model) {
        UserModel userModel = new UserModel();
        model.addAttribute("userModel", userModel);
        System.out.println("Register form");
        return "authentication/register-page";
    }

    @PostMapping("/register")
    public String processRegistration(@Valid @ModelAttribute("userModel") UserModel userModel,
                           BindingResult bindingResult, RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {
//        if (userService.findByEmail(userModel.getEmail()) != null) {
//            bindingResult.rejectValue("email",null,
//                    "Account with this email already exists.");
//            return "authentication/register-page";
//        }
//
//        if (userService.findByUsername(userModel.getUsername()) != null) {
//            bindingResult.rejectValue("username",null,
//                    "Account with this username already exists.");
//            return "authentication/register-page";
//        }

        if (!userModel.getPassword().equals(userModel.getConfirmPassword())) {
            bindingResult.rejectValue("confirmPassword",null,
                    "Password and confirm password do not match.");
            return "authentication/register-page";
        }

        if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            System.err.println("Error registering");
            return "authentication/register-page";
        }
        System.out.println("Successfully registered");
        redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("registrationComplete", "registrationComplete");
        return "redirect:/auth/login";
    }


}
```

This is the controller that handles the requests, I'm speaking about the @PostMapping part - the problem is when I uncomment the code that check if user exists, it doesn't run the sout() and addFlashAttribute() method, but why?

```
        System.out.println("Successfully registered");
        redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("registrationComplete", "200");
```

Every line of code that is after the first if statement is not executed even tried debugging it, it doesn't catch the break dot, tried also sout-ing to the console, doesn't work too. :(
No errors in the console also.
The problem is kinda strange, tried googleing it but I didn't found anything, hope you guys can help me!
Thank you in advance!

Comment: It's not clear from your question, bit it sounds like `findByEmail` is returning a non-null result, the body of the `if` is executing, and returning, hence the subsequent code isn't reached.

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem, I was throwing an exception if the user is not found in the Service class but the interesting thing was why there isn't anything about it in the console. So now I'm gonna think about how to check if user exist..

```
public UserEntity findByUsername(String username) {
    UserEntity userEntity = userRepository.findByUsername(username);
    if (userEntity == null) {
        throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User with username \"" + username + "\" is not found!" );
    }
    return userEntity;
}
```

Comment: Instead of using directly the findByUsername method, I've created new one doesUserExistsByUsername that returns true if user exist and false if not.